# Eclipse - How to define a batch file to be executed before Java configuration executes?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, batch-file, environment

I want to run a (Windows) batch script to set up **environment variables** before my Java program runs **within Eclipse**.

I know, that I could define environment variables in the run configuration but this is really **circumstancy**, as I have to do it a) for each run configuration and b) I've got a lot environment variables to set.

When I run the program outside of Eclipse, I easily run a batch script before executing or I create a batch script to set the env vars and then start the jvm.

It's also not the best way to set system wide variables via an external script before executing in Eclipse, so I thought, the easiest way would be to add the execution of a batch script before my program runs. Running the script out of my program does not get the variables into the program (as they only exist then in the sub process).

Comment: If you use Eclipse just for Java development, a possible solution could be starting Eclipse via a shortcut to a batch file and the batch file defines all the environment variables later needed by your Java applications started from within Eclipse before Eclipse is started as last line of the batch file. Each new process gets a copy of current variables of starting process which is the reason why this simple method could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to this, to Execute a Batch file, and continue after it's finished.

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {

      String Batchpath = "c:/test.bat";
      String executeCmd = "cmd /c start /wait " + Batchpath;
      final Process process = run.exec(executeCmd);  
      process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This approach does not bring the environment variables into my java program. It seems as they are known to the sub process only.

btw I set them with
set VAR=content

Comment: Alright, I don't know if what I do is a bad habit or not, but I program in more C++ than Java, and in C++, I use '#include <vars.hpp>' or something similar, to get variables into my program, and in Java, I sometimes use 'import', for the same thing.

Comment: My problem: When I run my Java application under z/OS or Unix, it's easy to define an environment in the batch job or script before executing the Java program. But for testing in Eclipse this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, alright. I'm not sure as to how I can get the variables into your program, then.